# How to find length of variable in state in react native?

Tags: react-native, native-base

```
this.state = {
  phone: ''
};
```

I want to find the length of the phone variable in state on change so that if the length is 10 I can perform an action.

**Also if possible can you let me know how can enable and disable native-base button programmatically in react native.**

*I'm a beginner in react native*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Get length of string

If the phone number is saved as a string then it is very easy. You can just do

```
let phoneNumberLength = this.state.phone.length
```

Then you can use it in an if statement

```
if (phoneNumberLength === 10) {
  // do something here
}
```

#### Native Base

The Button component in nativebase has a disabled prop that you can use. http://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#button-disabled-headref

You could set a value in your state to control whether the button is disabled or not. Calling `this.state({buttonDisabled: true})` will disable the button

```
this.state {
  buttonDisabled: false
}

<Button disabled={this.state.buttonDisabled} />
```

Comment: Perhaps if you showed what you are trying because that is the standard way for getting the length of a string, are you getting any error messages?

Comment: You need to show more code then, show the whole component that you are working on. Or create an expo snack demonstrating it not working.

Comment: now its working...but one out of context problem can I tell you ?

Comment: You should post a new question rather than appending it here.

Comment: I am enabling a button if the length of phone variable is 10 but after having length 10 the property of disabled is not getting change directly rather I have to backspace once input to work this.....

Comment: If you want the button to only be enabled if the length is 10 then you should try something like `<Button disabled={this.state.phone.length !== 10} />` that should disable the button when the phone number is not of length 10